# how to remove symbol from key value pair in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am having an dictionary like shown below here i need to remove the $ symbol in the keys and need to store in a separate array with same data as shown here can anyone help me how to remove dollar from all keys ?

```
var products = ["$50-$60": 50-60, "$30-$40": 30-40, "$0-$10": -10, "$20-$30": 20-30, "$90-and above": 90-, "$40-$50": 40-50, "$80-$90": 80-90, "$70-$80": 70-80, "$10-$20": 10-20, "$60-$70": 60-70]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you want the set of keys in an array as far as I understood

```
var dollarRemovedArray = products.map{$0.key.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")}
```

Output will be like this --

> ["50-60", "30-40", "0-10", "20-30", "90-and above", "40-50", "80-90",
>   "70-80", "10-20", "60-70"]

Comment: how to remove " " for every key in it ?@AdityaSrivastava

Comment: @user Didn't understand. Please elaborate a bit

Comment: in the output which i got i need to get 50-60 like that i need to remove " "

Comment: Why do you want to do that. The `dollarRemovedArray` is just an array of strings and hence when you access array using index like `dollarRemovedArray[0]`,  you will get 50-60.

Comment: by using that i need to find min and max with that numbers and need to assign to slider

Comment: @user See "$50-$60" cannot be converted to 50-60 since it's not a specified type like not an Int . So you have to workaround with "$50-$60"

Comment: without truncating $ can i find max and min value ?

Comment: @user I don't think so.

Comment: then how to find max n min with these key value pairs any idea how to implement this ?

Comment: @user for your array, Is 0 min and 90 is maximum ?Correct ?

Comment: @user  Try this `let arr = products.map{Int($0.key.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "").components(separatedBy: "-")[0])!}` and then use         `print(arr.min()) ` `print(arr.max())` for min and max

Comment: how to get the difference of those numbers any idea ? that means $10-$20 difference of these numbers